# DynamoDb cost for pagination

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If DynamoDb's paginated query feature is used, will the cost of getting the first page of results be equal to the cost of getting all page's results?

I only want to know know if any records match a query of how many records have a partition key value matching a specific value and a sort key value less than a specified value, so I was thinking of using a paginated query with a limit of one. If the query returns any results for the first page then I know there's a match. I want to avoid fetching every record, because often there will be hundreds of thousands of matches but I only need to know if there is at least one.

Answer (score 0):

You only pay for what you read. If you have a limit of 1 then you only pay to read one item.

However, if you use a filter expression then you pay to read whatever items match your KeyConditionExpression and the FilterExpression is applied afterwards.